# MySQL percentages in a single query

Tags: mysql

So far I've got this:\

```
SELECT Bike_Number, MaintFaultDetails, MaintactionTaken, MaintfaultDate, MaintActionDate,
       COUNT(*) 
FROM   MaintHistory
WHERE  (MaintfaultDate + 5) < MaintactionTaken 

SELECT Bike_Number, MaintFaultDetails, MaintactionTaken, MaintfaultDate, MaintActionDate,
       COUNT(*) 
FROM   MaintHistory
```

What would I add/edit so that it calculates the percentags of bikes that took longer than 5 days

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: Do you actually need anything besides `COUNT(*)` in your queries? (e.g. `Bike_Number`, `MaintFaultDetails`, etc.)

Comment: Just need it to display the amount of bikes that took longer than 5 days. Count seemed like the logical thing to do make it work

An example would be 

|Bikes overdue|
| 10%         |

Nothing too flash, just display a number really

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
 SELECT Bike_Number, MaintFaultDetails, MaintactionTaken, MaintfaultDate, MaintActionDate,
   Concat(count(Bike_Number)*100/COUNT(*).'%' ) as percent
 FROM   MaintHistory
 WHERE  DATE_ADD(MaintfaultDate, INTERVAL +5 DAY) < MaintactionTaken
```

Comment: Comes up with an error:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 3
The % is highlighted

Comment: then you are using oracle not mysql ? why you are using mysql tag then ?

Comment: I was under the impression Oracle used MySQL, if not then I apologize